# PowerBI Matrix with "All" Cell data?

Tags: powerbi, office365, dax

In [How can I create a relationship matrix in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54232317) I asked for a way to create a relationship matrix in Excel - copied here for convenience:

```
1 A X
1 A Y
1 B X             A   B   C
1 B Z         1  X,Y X,Z
2 A Z   ==>   2   Z   X   Y
2 B X         3   Y   Z
3 A Y
3 A Z
2 C Y
```

Currently I am evaluating O365 PowerBI for the same feature. There is a matrix visualisation that looks promising, but for cell data one can not choose "all" or a "concat"-operation like TEXTJOIN. It has only "First" or "Last".

Any way to get that relationship matrix feature in PowerBI ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are analogous concatenation functions in DAX as well as M. I'll give a DAX solution here since it allows more dynamic interaction and is quite simple.

Assuming your the columns of `Table1` are `Number`, `Letter1`, and `Letter2` and you have `Number` on rows and `Letter1` on columns, you can use this measure to get the matrix you're after:

```
All = CONCATENATEX ( VALUES ( Table1[Letter2] ), Table1[Letter2], "," )
```

[image: Concat Matrix]

The [`VALUES` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/values-function-dax) returns a list of all distinct values of the column argument that are within the current filter context. The [`CONCATENATEX` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/concatenatex-function-dax) then iterates through this list/table (1st argument) and for each item concatenates the value/expression `Table1[Letter2]` (2nd argument) separating each one with `,` (3rd argument).

Comment: Still no access to Power BI Desktop yet. What is "DAX" and "M"?

Comment: DAX is the language used to write measures (like in my answer). M is the language used in the query editor when importing data.

Comment: Right-click on the table and choose "New measure".

Answer (score 1):

Yes Matrix Feature is available.Expected Result using **PowerBI** is here :

[image]

**Steps Are :**
Duplicate your table if you want to compare result.

1. Add New Measure

   ```
   Measure = CONCATENATEX(Table1,(Table1[Letter2]),", ")
   ```

If you want Disitinct Total then use @Alexis answer code.

```
All = CONCATENATEX ( VALUES ( Table1[Letter2] ), Table1[Letter2], "," )
```

2. UnSelect Column '`Letter2`' and select '`measure`' Column
3. Change Visual table to 'Matrix' Type
4. Change matrix Properties Row and Column SubToal to `Off`
5. Your Expected Result is ready

You can actual visual check step Here [image]

Thank you. let me know if you have any concern.

Comment: Note that this version of the measure may produce duplicates of letters as seen in the animation when the total rows/columns are included.

Comment: total rows/columns is not requirement in question. Its matches with there expected output.

Comment: I just wanted to point out the potential difference. I don't actually know which version OP would prefer.

Comment: @Mr. Bhosale I like your explanation and style very much, but as Alexis was faster I accepted his answer. Sadly I couldn't split the bounty. Thanks, the gif is very helpful!